# Reference Mongodb schema from other microservices

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql, typegoose

I currently have a microservice architecture powered by Apollo Federation, where a service has its own database. Consider this example, the user's service has its own database, the posts service has its own database, and the comments service has its own database. Currently, each schema sits in its own service, but each of these models references each other. For example

```js
// posts.model
const PostSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    name: String,
    user: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
});
```

In this case, a Post has the corresponding user attached to it. I am using `typegoose` alongside `type-graphql` in another microservice while the rest microservices are written in plain javascript. Now in my `typegoose` class, I am trying to achieve the same thing above. I have a class `(model)` that is referencing another entity in a different service/database. How do I represent it in my typegoose model? E.g

```js
export class Post {
@GqlField(() => String, { nullable: true })
    @prop()
    title: string;

    @GqlField(() => User)
    @prop({ ref: () => User, required: true })
    user: Ref<User>; // this is meant to reference user in the user-service.

    @GqlField(() => String)
    @prop({required: true,})
    name: string;
}
```

Do I use an `abstract class` to represent the `User model`, if yes, how do I go about this? Or is there another method that I can use to achieve this? I tried creating a User model class in the current microservice, but that user's model is going to be registered on the current database connection and I don't want that.

I'll appreciate any advice, thank you in advance.

Comment: if you want to share models, i would recommend to share the whole schemas / models between the services (like a dependency), also for your question about accessing `User` from a different service, could you tell me if i understood correctly that: `User` is in a different service (project) that from where you are trying to access it from and each service (project) has its own dedicated mongodb database (not just collection / connection)?

Comment: @hasezoey yes you are correct, each service has its own dedicated MongoDB database.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is called "Cross-Database Population", where mongoose has [a documentation page for it](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#cross-db-populate), where the TL;DR; basically is:

Either pass a *Model instance* to `ref` (which currently is not supported by typegoose) or use the `model` option in a populate call.

Example:
(you still require the Schema from the other services and a database connection to those databases)

```
@modelOptions({ existingConnection: UserDBConnection }) // this can also be set in the call for "getModelForClass"
class User {
  @prop()
  public name?: string;
}

const UserModel = getModelForClass(User);
// or if setting the connection here
const UserModel = getModelForClass(User, { existingConnection: UserDBConnection });

// without setting a explicit database, "mongoose.connection" will be used (which is the default connection in mongoose)
class Post {
  @prop({ ref: () => User })
  public user?: Ref<User>;
}

const PostModel = getModelForClass(PostModel);

// somewhere later in your code
await postdoc.populate({ path: 'user', model: UserModel }).execPopulate();
```